Check if today is the last monday of the current month in power automate
I'm building a scheduled cloud flow in Power Automate that needs to run only on the last Monday of each month. How can I check if the current date is the last Monday of the current month using Power Automate expressions?
If the flow runs today (September 30th, 2024), the trigger should be true and all actions would run

Does the answer by Mira Ghaly here do what you want? https://community.powerplatform.com/forums/thread/details/?threadid=c7eebe85-75a6-49fd-821c-28b29e44205e

Using a trigger condition would be fairly hard to support so I wouldn't go down that path unless you really want to, it would be quite verbose.  I'm not sure if you wanted to do that or not but I suggest steering clear of it anyway.
These expressions in the flow will do it for you.  After the last step, you could have a condition to terminate or not depending on the outcome.

These are the steps and conditions ...
Initialize Current Date
I've just done this with a date from my own timezone.
convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'AUS Eastern Standard Time')

Is Monday
This will provide a boolean result if the day you're running it on is a Monday.
equals(dayOfWeek(variables('Current Date')), 1)

Is Within 7 Days Of EOM
This is the trickier one.  This determines how many days are left between now and the end of the month.  There may be a better way but this works.
lessOrEquals(sub(int(formatDateTime(addDays(concat(formatDateTime(variables('Current Date'), 'yyyy-MM'), '-01'), -1), 'dd')), int(formatDateTime(variables('Current Date'), 'dd'))), 7)

Initialize Is Last Monday Of Month
If the last two operations equal true, it's the last Monday of the week.
and(outputs('Is_Monday'), outputs('Is_Within_7_Days_Of_EOM'))

That should give you what you need.

You can achieve it by following these steps:

Create an scheduled flow that runs everyday
Add an expression as a trigger condition which will check if the current is last monday (or whatever you want to check)



@and(
    equals(dayOfWeek(utcNow()), 1), // Check if today is Monday
    greater(
        split(string(addDays(utcNow(), 7)), '-')?[1], // Get the month of the date 7 days from now
        split(string(utcNow()), '-')?[1] // Get the current month
    )
)



Logic behind: Check if today is monday AND if Adding 7 days changes the month (month will change if it is last week)

You can copy this same expression on trigger condition


I think the below one is the easiest and most convenient one.
Set varCurrentDate with convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'Arab Standard Time')
and then use a boolean variable to set the below formula to determine if the current date is the last week (7 days) of the month:
not(
    equals(
        formatDateTime(variables('varCurrentDate'), 'MM'),
        formatDateTime(addDays(variables('varCurrentDate'), 7), 'MM')
    )
)

